# French citizenship after studying in French University

Tags: france, citizenship

As per the [official cite](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2213) one can apply for naturalization in France after completing 2 years in a French superior institute

```
2 ans d'études accomplies avec succès pour obtenir un diplôme d'un établissement d'enseignement supérieur français
```

My question is that if the normal duration of a course is 1 yr and for some reasons it is extended to 2 years, what are the rules in such a case? In particular one may assume that 2 yrs degree would be defined by number of credit hours and if so would one have to take a few more credit hours to be eligible. Where can one find more information regarding this issue?

Comment: Nope. It depends on the program of study. The program of study has to be 2 years. The text on the service public website is not the same as actual text of the law (article 21-18 of the "code civil"). The law says: "Le stage mentionné à l'article 21-17 est réduit à deux ans : 1° Pour l'étranger qui a accompli avec succès deux années d'études supérieures en vue d'acquérir un diplôme délivré par une université ou un établissement d'enseignement supérieur français". The practice of the prefectures is it that they check if the program is for two years.

Comment: @ar5976 That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Indeed. I was considering it as an answer, but I have no "official" proof of this practice in the prefectures. Indeed the law on this only states that a foreigner can apply for naturalization if s/he "has successfully completed two years of higher education with a view to obtaining a diploma awarded by a French university or higher education institution." It doesn't actually say that the program itself has to be at least two years long. I only know of this through different fora and discussion.